# How to convert JQuery to vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert the below `JQuery` code to a vanilla `Javascript` version, but got stuck on the loop. This is my current try:

**Javascript:**

```
var x = document.getElementById("Table1"), d = x.getElementByTagName("td");

for (let row of x.rows)
{    
    for(let cell of row.cells)
    {
        var td_content = $(this).text();

        if (td_content != "") {
            hide = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And below is the original `JQuery` code I'm trying to convert.

**JQuery:**

```
$('#Table1 td').each(function()
{
    var td_content = $(this).text();

    if (td_content != "") {
        hide = false;
    }
})
```

Comment: What is .rows? just do x.getElementsByTagName("td") and loop through that array

Comment: Maybe you can use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) like `document.querySelectorAll("#Table1 td")`. Then you can traverse the returned `NodeList` with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `document.querySelectorAll` for easy conversion to vanilla JS.

```
var hide = true;
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('#Table1 td');
cells.forEach(function(cell) {
  if (cell.innerText !== '') {
    hide = false;
  }
});
console.log(hide);
```